# request promise: invalid url

Tags: node.js, request, request-promise

When I use the node js request-promise function with the following parameters, I get an error: Invalid URI. Can someone please help

```
  var request = require('request-promise');
  request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/test
```

/api/test is a path on the server

Comment: Where is `/api/test` supposed to point to? It is not a valid URL. Protocol, IP/DN missing.

Comment: its a server path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative uri for node.js request library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026346/relative-uri-for-node-js-request-library)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the url path is incorrect. The url requires

> protocol(http/https in this case)://ip-address/domain-name:port(optional if configured in nginx)/route-to-api-endpoint.

example:

> https://192.168.2.44:3000/api/test

or

> http://jasmine.website.com/api/test

Update the url and you can make api requests.